# Can I Use Laravel's Blade Directive in My Controller?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want to use the blade directive in my controller, in this case I've created an email template custom where email messages retrieved from a database and an email message that I could write my own tags `[app_name], [button url=my url]Text[/button], etc`.

When I write `[app_name]` it will be 'Site Name' and also when I write `[button url=my url]Text[/button]` it will call `@component('mail::button', ['url'=>'my url'])Text@endcomponent`.

So, can I use laravel blade in my controller?

Comment: You can't (at least not in a straght forward way) and shouldn't, the controller should not be responsible for presentation elements. Just make a view with what you need and pass the parameters from the controller to the view. You can just make a view via `$view= view(myview)->with(..)` and then use it to do whatever you need (e.g. `$view->render()` to get the complied markup).

Comment: But, do you have another soution for that? Essentially I want to send an email with the Laravel default button component.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. The default emailing system in laravel allows you to send an email using a blade template as the content. `Email::send("view.name", [ viewdata ], function ($mail) { /* do more things to the mail object */ })`;

Answer (score 0):

You can pass **array** to the blade file. Have a look at below code

$data['app_name'] = 'Your app name';
return $this->view('emails.orders.shipped', $data);

Now in your blade you can access variable **$app_name**

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that's not what i mean